# SFDX hello:org plugin not available when installed from npmjs

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

I've create a SFDX Plugin with `sfdx plugins:generate`. When the plugin is linked using `sfdx plugins:link .` the command `hello:org` is available and work properly.
When this same plugin is deployed to npmjs and installed using `sfdx plugins:install` the command `hello:org` is not even available.

**Does anybody knows the reason why?**

screenshot when using the plugin from local directory:
[image]

screenshot when using the plugin from npmjs:
[image]
Note the command `hello:org` is not even available after install.

Evidence of plugin installed:
[image]

The source code: https://github.com/forcexp/autocode

The npmjs page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@forcexp/autocode

Comment: What command are you running in command line ? Can you screenshot your terminal ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava I've updated the description with the screenshot.

Comment: when you run sfdx plugins  , what do you see ?

Comment: Question edited with the screenshot

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You  need to run 'sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff' command in terminal and restart VS code. Terminal may prompt you to get confirmation before installing it.